# Plaftormio requires upload_port field while docs says the opposite

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio

Here my `plaformio.ini` file:

```
[env:myproject]
platform = espressif32
board = myboard
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
    openslab-osu/SSLClient@^1.6.7
    knolleary/PubSubClient@^2.8
    bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.16.1
    stevemarple/MCP342x@^1.0.2
    nickgammon/Regexp@^0.1.0
monitor_speed = 9600
board_build.partitions = min_spiffs.csv
extra_scripts = reset.py
```

When I build the code I get this error:

> Error: Please specify `upload_port` for environment or use global `--upload-port` option.

But the official [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_upload.html#upload-port) states:

> If upload_port isn’t specified, then PlatformIO will try to detect it automatically.

I understand it's not mandatory.
Am I wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.60.2 under Ubuntu 20.04 with PlatformIO Core 5.2.3 Home 3.4.0.

Comment: What exactly is it you're having trouble with? The wording _will try to detect it automatically_ conveys that autodetection may or may not work. It obviously doesn't work in this case (to be honest, I don't quite imagine how it could pick the one ESP serial port out of all the ports in your system correctly), so go ahead and enter your port manually.

Comment: @Tarmo, sorry I don't agree. 1. failing to detect a serial port is something related to the programming operations. It makes no sense to trigger a *build* error. 2. the problem is not the failing of detection, but the missing `upload_port` parameter! 3. for about one year I successfully programmed my ESP32 *without* this parameter. If the last update has changed anything, it should be highlighted in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, building code should not require specifying a port. If you've started encountering this problem after an update, it's probably worth mentioning this.